# How to select the first of these buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, greasemonkey

I want to use a Greasemonkey script to click a button.

The button HTML starts like below; there are 3 buttons, corresponding to 48/50/52 respectively. The 48/50/52 are not identical, so is there some way to selectively click the button by mean of choosing the first one in the `class="modeNum"`?

I just want the first one to be clicked.

The button code:

```
<dl class="numSize">
    <dt>size:</dt>
    <dd class="modeNum">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" rev="6" rel="3">48</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" rev="10" rel="3">50</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" rev="1" rel="1">52</a></dd>
        <dd class="dps">
        <a href="javascript:;">size chart</a>
    </dd>
    <dd class="clear"></dd>
</dl>
```

...and when the second button is clicked, the code changes to:

```
<dl class="numSize">
    <dt>size:</dt>
    <dd class="modeNum">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" rev="6" rel="3">48</a>
        <a class="Active" href="javascript:void(0);" rev="10" rel="3">50</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" rev="1" rel="1">52</a></dd>
        <dd class="dps">
        <a href="javascript:;">size chart</a>
    </dd>
    <dd class="clear"></dd>
</dl>
```

**How to use `document.querySelector` to select the first `<a>` element?**

Answer (score 2):

Re:

> How to use `document.querySelector` to select the first element?

That's easy as `document.querySelector` always only returns the *first* matching element (if any).

You would merely use:

```
var firstBtn = document.querySelector ("dl.numSize > dd.modeNum > a");
if (firstBtn) {
    // DO YOUR CLICK OR WHATEVER, HERE.
}
```

---

Or, if you want to be extra sure:

```
var firstBtn = document.querySelector ("dl.numSize > dd.modeNum > a:first-of-type");
if (firstBtn) {
    // DO YOUR CLICK OR WHATEVER, HERE.
}
```

---

The jQuery selector is identical in this case:

```
var firstBtn = $("dl.numSize > dd.modeNum > a:first-of-type");
if (firstBtn.length) {
    // DO YOUR CLICK OR WHATEVER, HERE.
}
```

---

Reference:

- [W3C, CSS Selector spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)
- [CSS3 Selector compatibility](http://fmbip.com/litmus/#css3-selectors)

Comment: Adams, thank you for your help.

that works, and the reference is very helpful for learning this topic. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.  If this solves your problem, then [tick the check-mark next to this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).